# Mongoose, update() vs save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Which is more efficient for updating parts of a document, `save()` or `update()`?

Let this be an example of a `Schema`:

```
var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    subtasks: Array
});
```

If I `push()` - via regular JS array methods, some `subtasks` into it and then call `save()`, would mongoose send the *whole* `todo` document to the database server or just the `subtasks` that was added?

I'm under that impression that using `update()` to `$push` a subtask it simply performs the operation *directly on the database*, sending only the `$push`-ed subtask through the wire as opposed to `update()` which would just send the `subtask` over the wire.

Comment: You can actually see what gets sent to be saved when you have debugging enabled.

Comment: Use `mongoose.set('debug', true);`, then watch the console output

Comment: And when I work with `save()` it only sends what was changed to be saved

Comment: @You Thanks - care to add it as an answer?

Comment: Done :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually see what gets sent to be saved when you have debugging enabled:

`mongoose.set('debug', true);`

And when I've worked with `save()` it only sends what was changed to be saved.