# Mongoose MODEL update() vs save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passwords, authorization

There were a [question about `update()` vs `save()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010045/mongoose-update-vs-save), but it was targeting some different stuff (I guess, purely related `mongoose.Schema` methods, but not to the actual document)

I have a following scenario, where user logs in to website:

- I need to load document (find it by `userModel.email`)
- Check if a `userModel.password` hash matches to what was recieved
- Update `userModel.lastLogin` timestamp
- Append authorization event to `userModel.myEvents[]` array

So I am wondering - **what is a proper way to go?**

1)

```
let foundUser = userModel.findOne({ email: recievedEmail });
if(foundUser.password != recievedPassword)
    return res.status(400).json({e: "invalid pass"});
foundUser.lastLogin = new Date();
foundUser.myEvents.push(authEvent)
foundUser.save();
```

2)

```
let foundUser = userModel.findOne({ email: recievedEmail });
if(foundUser.password != recievedPassword)
    return res.status(400).json({e: "invalid pass"});
foundUser.update({
    $push: { myEvents: authEvent },
    $set: { lastLogin: new Date() }
});
foundUser.save();
```

3)

```
let foundUser = userModel.findOne({ email: recievedEmail });
if(foundUser.password != recievedPassword)
    return res.status(400).json({e: "invalid pass"});
userModel.updateOne({_id: foundUser._id}, {$push: ...
// seems no save is required here?
```

4)

```
// I am doing it wrong, and you have faster/higher/stronger variant?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to call foundUser.save() when you are using foundUser.update() method.

And, all the above methods are almost equally efficient as there are two calls being made to the database. So, it comes down to your personal preference.

And, one more method with just one call to the database can be executed in this manner:-

```
let foundUser = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
 { email: recievedEmail, password: hashedPassword },
 { $set: { lastLogin: new Date() }, $push: { myEvents: authEvent } }
);
```

In this method, if a user with given email and password exists, that user will be updated and corresponding updated document will be returned in a `foundUser` variable. So you don't have to perform an additional check on password: If `findOneAndUpdate()` returns a document, it means password and email matched. You have just to check for null or undefined on the returned document for no match.

Comment: *"First of all, you don't need to call foundUser.save() when you are using foundUser.update() method."* In that case NOTHING is updated in the database, I tried.

Comment: It returns a promise. Do you await for the result?

Comment: this is not required. i use Robo3T and see that its NEVER updated (without save). because foundUser is a document, and not a model. However, you proposed much better way of doing it, so that is the answer.

Comment: Robo3t does not use mongoose. You cannot execute mongoose commands in robo3t

Comment: Why do i need to execute mongoose commands in robo3t? I just can see database with it. And I am seeing that `DOCUMENT.update()` does local update but not actually saves, like `MODEL.findandupdate()` do.. that is probably mongoose internals

Comment: I personally have not tried using update on document ever but in mongoose documents it says there is a method on document for update. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update

Comment: Yes, and it returns query, not requiring awaits. (Query is to be executed, if you write `save()` after calling `update()`). . But that's offtopic now. How can I determine if `await userModel.findOneAndUpdate()` succeeds or not? Does it return document/throws an exception as usual?

Comment: You can execute queries by appending .exec() at end of the query too. If findOneAndUpdate returns a document, it means password and email matched. So just check for null or undefined on the returned document for no match.

Comment: Thanks alot! Now it is a complete answer, probably best one possible. Good Job! You may append a details from last comment (It fully covers auth checking method).

Comment: Also, just one off topic thing. I see you are using a myEvents field on user which I assume will probably hold an infinite number of events. But as this list of events increases, you are gonna run into some issues. This is not the best way to define a schema by embedding array inside another document. Instead it should have a separate collection of its own with user id as a reference. This is because mongodb documents have a 16mb limit and your single document will eventually run past that limit as you save more events. If thats your case do look into it.

Comment: It stores ObjectIds: authEvent is an `Schema.ObjectId` type. I have separate collection for events, and no need to even `await` for event to be added (in order to authorize user or not) ;-) I wrote here like that for simplicity. Also I've managed to extend your answer a bit, to cover return values details. Check it please, is it all correct?